# golang sort slices of slice by first element

Tags: go, slice

i'm trying to do sorting for my slice child's (inside a slice), my slice is created from

```
var s [][]int64
s = append(s, []int64{2, 60, 55, 5})
s = append(s, []int64{4, 45, 35, 10})
s = append(s, []int64{1, 200, 160, 40})
fmt.Println(s) # [[2 60 55 5] [4 45 35 10] [1 200 160 40]]
```

how to sort it's value by first element to become :

```
[[1 200 160 40] [2 60 55 5] [4 45 35 10]]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Go lang sort a 2D Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42629541/go-lang-sort-a-2d-array)

Comment: @JimB there is an interesting edge case here since the element being sorted may be empty, so the sort.Slice function is more interesting than the referenced duplicate answers.

Comment: @colminator: I'm not sure how interesting that is, as it should be obvious whether you need to check the bounds or not. This is really just a form of the regularly posted "how to sort X by Y", and we don't need separate answers for every possible combination of types and fields for X and Y. At some point you need to be able to apply the documentation. (that said, if you feel it deserves an answer, go ahead and vote to reopen ;))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question does not state what should be done with empty slices, so treating them like an empty word in a conventional word-sort, would put them first, so this would handle that edge case:

```
import "sort"

sort.Slice(s, func(i, j int) bool {
    // edge cases
    if len(s[i]) == 0 && len(s[j]) == 0 {
        return false // two empty slices - so one is not less than other i.e. false
    }
    if len(s[i]) == 0 || len(s[j]) == 0 {
        return len(s[i]) == 0 // empty slice listed "first" (change to != 0 to put them last)
    }

    // both slices len() > 0, so can test this now:
    return s[i][0] < s[j][0]
})
```

Playground [version](https://play.golang.org/p/BQgpTPmkCGX).

Answer (score 0):

```
func slicesort(arr [][]int){
   
    sort.Slice(arr, func(i, j int) bool{
        if arr[i][1]>arr[j][1]{
            return true
        }
        if arr[i][1]==arr[j][1] && arr[i][0]<arr[j][0]{
            return true
        }
        return false
    })
}

func main() {
    s :=[][]int{{2,8},{2,9},{3,8},{1,9},{3,9}}
    slicesort(s)
    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If applicable to your project, you can also utilise the [deepsort](https://github.com/gbatagian/deepsort) package - note: I am the author of the package.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/gbatagian/deepsort"
)

func main() {
    var s [][]int64
    s = append(s, []int64{2, 60, 55, 5})
    s = append(s, []int64{4, 45, 35, 10})
    s = append(s, []int64{1, 200, 160, 40})

    deepsort.DeepSort(&s, []int{0})
    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

which would output:

```bash
[[1 200 160 40] [2 60 55 5] [4 45 35 10]]
```